# Render actual YAML data within HTML using React/Gatsby

Tags: html, reactjs, yaml, gatsby

I am writing an application that shows different configurations my system has. These configurations are saved on disk as YAML files. I am using GatsbyJS to generate the pages.

I am using the `js-yaml` library to load the yamls into memory and it's `safeDump()` function to dump the yaml into the `div` but I get the yaml as a one line string (yikes!!)

I need to show the YAML as-is in the webpage as it's seen in the file system. When a user clicks on a system, I have a `div` on the right side where I want to load the YAML (with proper formatting of course). I googled around to see if there were any solutions but I am not sure yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a quick solution I found was wrapping my `yaml.safedump(data)` line with `<pre>` tags and it renders great.

so the solution so far is:

`<pre>yaml.safedump(data, { indent: 4, flowLevel: 3 })</pre>`

Comment: This would print "yaml.safedump(data, { indent: 4, flowLevel: 3 })" as it is on the webpage. Do I miss something ?